# PREV and NEXT using the GET function with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a previous and next button, I do not know how to decrease and increase the id using the get function. Can anyone please help, thank you.

**PREVIOUS BUTTON CODE**

```
<?php
include('db.php');
//now execut Select statement on table
$title = $_GET['title'];

$SQL = mysqli_query($db, "
    SELECT * 
    FROM imageverse 
    WHERE ( 
        id = IFNULL((SELECT max(id) FROM imageverse WHERE id < id='".$title."'),0)
    );"
);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL)) {
    $date = $row['date'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    echo "<h3>Prev - <a href = 'bibleread_post1.php?title=" . $title . "'#top'>". $title ."</a></h3>";
}
// Close your database connection
mysqli_close($db_conx);
?>
```

**NEXT BUTTON CODE**

```
<?php
include('db.php');
//now execut Select statement on table
$title = $_GET['title'];

$SQL = mysqli_query($db, "
    SELECT * FROM imageverse 
    WHERE ( 
        id = IFNULL((SELECT min(id) FROM imageverse WHERE id > id='".$title."'),0) 
    );"
);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SQL)) {
    $date = $row['date'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    echo "<h3><a href = 'bibleread_post1.php?title=" . $title . "'#top'>". $title ."</a> - Next</h3>";
}
// Close your database connection
mysqli_close($db_conx);
?>
```

Comment: Just add a parameter on the URL (e.g. `bibleread_post1.php?title=MyTtitle&id=100`) then use `$_GET['id']`. As another note you should sanitise untrusted input such as $_GET, and escape SQL queries. It's best to use PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: Really do not want to use the id number at all. Do you have another suggestion on how to code a prev and next button (not pagination). I have researched on how to get a prev and next button but mostly all the researched involved pagination. Please forgive me for I am new at this and the code you are viewing was given to me.

Comment: Depends what you're actually after. You could put the id in a session variable, then use `&dir=prev`/`&dir=next`.  I don't really understand what you mean by not wanting to use the id when you asked how to decrease/increase the id.

Comment: Are you talking about `++$title` and `--$title`?

Comment: Sorry about that. When they click on the title using this code ---------- <a href = "bibleread_post.php?title=' . $title . '"#top">$title</a> ---------------- I would like for it to not show the id in the url address bar. Just would like the title to show only. Is this possible? Is there a way to do a previous and next using the phpself?

Comment: You should use $_POST for that.

Comment: Do not use this code in production, you should never pass unsanitized data to an SQL Query! And if you could switch to PDO instead of mysqli function it would be great.